# Manifest merger failed with AGP 8.3.0

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to upgrade my project to AGP 8.3.0 but I'm getting the error:

```
Attribute property#android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG@resource value=(@xml/ga_ad_services_config) from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:21.5.1] AndroidManifest.xml:32:13-58
    is also present at [com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:22.6.0] AndroidManifest.xml:92:13-59 value=(@xml/gma_ad_services_config).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:resource"' to <property> element at AndroidManifest.xml to override.
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

I don't have anything related to `AD_SERVICES_CONFIG` in my manifest file.

Comment: I did as suggested. Created a new property with `tools:replace="android:resource" `<property
            android:name="android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG"
            android:resource="@xml/gma_ad_services_config"
            tools:replace="android:resource" />

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Problem is definitely not with your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, but rather the files that are bundled with the external Google services libraries that you have implemented in your application. Yes, sometimes they may conflict with each other (as all manifests are merged during app build) and this seems to be the case.

Eventually, Google will address this issue, but for now you can either downgrade your dependencies (need to figure out which ones, but AGP 8.2.2 didn't have this problem AFAIK).

Or, just do as suggested by the error log, and solve the conflict by adding this block to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<manifest
    ...

    <application
        ...

        <property
            android:name="android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG"
            android:resource="@xml/gma_ad_services_config"
            tools:replace="android:resource" />
        
        ...
    </application>

    ...
</manifest>
```

**Note:** I would still recommend going back to AGP 8.2.2 if your project is important, since new releases are always risky and this might not be the only problem in the updated Gradle plugin

Comment: thanks! I ended keeping 8.2.2, which was the version I had before. Agree with you, can't risk it.

Comment: Wait why does it occur? Is it a bug on some version of the dependency or gradle ? Is it a known bug? Or is it documented anywhere that I need to do this?

Comment: @androiddeveloper seems like a bug, a version conflict between latest agp and firebase/gms libs

Comment: @SergeyEmeliyanov Was it reported? How did you know what to put?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I believe it's been reported, there are numerous reports on issuetracker.google.com mentioning the log. About the solution, attribute marker `tools:replace` is a common pill, which reconfigures the main manifest and solves the version conflict, such as the aforementioned.

Comment: @SergeyEmeliyanov Maybe this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/327696048 ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Yes

Answer (score 8):

Note that you have to give a version number when importing the play-services-ads, it doesn't work like Analytics which takes the version from the BOM.

(App-Level) gradle for example:

```
implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.3"))
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics")
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.6.0")
```

Add this property to your Manifest file (inside application - above or below activities):

```
<property
            android:name="android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG"
            android:resource="@xml/gma_ad_services_config"
            tools:replace="android:resource" />
```

Sync the project and run it.
Don't forget to init the library (Better to do it in the application class - with the Application Context):

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        MobileAds.initialize(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why "Better to do it in the application class - with the Application Context" ??

Answer (score 2):

Checking the affected libraries, actually the correct behavior is this and not the previous one from IDE/AGP standpoint.

I do not recommend to use the previous version of AGP that compiled the app without report this problem as it may cause undesired overrides.

One of the conflicting config files(`gma_ad_services_config.xml`) allows both *Attribution API* and *Topics API* the other one (`ga_ad_services_config.xml`) just *Attribution API*.

Answer (score 1):

I fix this error by adding this  tag to the  tag in the manifest.

```xml
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value="@string/APP_NUMBER" />
    <property
        android:name="android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG"
        android:resource="@xml/gma_ad_services_config"
        tools:replace="android:resource" />
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding this provider inside **application** tag in **AndroidManifest.xml** will solve this issue.

> **This will guide the build system to prioritize resources from the "play-services-ads-lite" library during the build process.**

```
<application
    ....
    ....

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
        tools:node="remove" />

</application>
```