# Manifest merger failed : Attribute property#android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG with AGP 8.3.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, admob

I'm getting following compile time error after upgrading to **APG:8.3.0**

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute property#android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG@resource 
value=(@xml/ga_ad_services_config) from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:21.5.1]
AndroidManifest.xml:32:13-58 is also present at [com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:22.6.0]
AndroidManifest.xml:92:13-59 value=(@xml/gma_ad_services_config).
```

Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:resource"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml to override?

Any solution regarding admob, instead of suppressing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manifest merger failed with AGP 8.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78085458/manifest-merger-failed-with-agp-8-3-0)