Flutter Android Build: Manifest merger failed
when building my Flutter app for Android I receive the following error:


Attribute property#android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG@resource value=(@xml/ga_ad_services_config) from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:22.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:32:13-58
        is also present at [com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:23.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:92:13-59 value=(@xml/gma_ad_services_config).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:resource"' to <property> element at AndroidManifest.xml to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute property#android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG@resource value=(@xml/ga_ad_services_config) from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:22.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:32:13-58
        is also present at [com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:23.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:92:13-59 value=(@xml/gma_ad_services_config).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:resource"' to <property> element at AndroidManifest.xml to override.



I tried following the instructions in this post, but sadly this leads to a "Parsing Error" of my AndroidManifest.xml which I don't know how to solve either..
Additional details:


My AGP Version: 8.5

google_mobile_ads: ^5.1.0

// inside android/app/build.gradle:
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.0.0'
}



Any idea how to solve this error?
Thank you!

This SO question answers it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78204140/android-project-problem-when-implementing-admob
