Circular dependency between the following tasks after updating Gradle Plugin and Firebase Crashlytics Plugin
I have updated the following deps
androidGradlePlugin = "8.2.2"
firebaseBom = "32.8.1"
firebaseCrashlyticsPlugin = "2.9.9"

to
androidGradlePlugin = "8.4.0"
firebaseBom = "33.0.0"
firebaseCrashlyticsPlugin = "3.0.0"

And now the project can't be build:
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug
\--- :app:mergeDebugResources
     +--- :app:generateDebugLocaleConfig
     |    \--- :app:extractDebugSupportedLocales
     |         \--- :app:injectCrashlyticsMappingFileIdDebug
     |              +--- :app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug (*)
     |              \--- :app:kspDebugKotlin
     |                   +--- :app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug (*)
     |                   \--- :app:processDebugResources
     |                        +--- :app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths
     |                        |    \--- :app:injectCrashlyticsMappingFileIdDebug (*)
     |                        +--- :app:mergeDebugResources (*)
     |                        +--- :app:processDebugManifest
     |                        |    \--- :app:processDebugMainManifest
     |                        |         \--- :app:extractDeepLinksDebug
     |                        |              \--- :app:injectCrashlyticsMappingFileIdDebug (*)
     |                        \--- :app:processDebugManifestForPackage
     |                             \--- :app:processDebugManifest (*)
     \--- :app:injectCrashlyticsMappingFileIdDebug (*)

I noticed injectCrashlyticsMappingFileIdDebug appears too much but why?
it works with firebaseCrashlyticsPlugin = "2.9.9" and with the newest versions for:
androidGradlePlugin = "8.4.0"
firebaseBom = "33.0.0"

but had to add to the manifest:
<property
    android:name="android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG"
    android:resource="@xml/gma_ad_services_config"
    tools:replace="android:resource" />

to fix the following issue when using the latest Gradle plugin version

check this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/327696048

@BobSmith my issue is not about AD_SERVICES_CONFIG, it's already reported here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78085458/manifest-merger-failed-with-agp-8-3-0 and has the answer and I have also added the solution for this one here for previous version of plugin... so why did you posted this link? The issue about the latest version of plugin and Circular dependency between the following tasks

I thought you haven't checked that and I just tried to help you :) no bad intentions.

Update: (20-05-2024)
It looks like this issue has been rectified in the 3.0.1 release of com.google.firebase.crashlytics (release notes dated May 13th, 2024).
I've given it a quick test and can confirm that bumping the dependency up from 2.9.9 to 3.0.1 worked a treat in my case.

Stopgap Solution: (13-05-2024)
⚠️ The below feedback has since been superseded. See the update, above. ⚠️
I came across similar woes after updating com.google.firebase.crashlytics from 2.9.9 -> 3.0.0 and after a bit of investigation, I came across this thread and comment.
The above linked comment references a stopgap solution as a workaround for the firebaseCrashlyticsPlugin circular dependency issue. Judging by feedback in the original discussion thread, it seems to do the trick. I haven't personally jumped through the hoops associated with this workaround as yet, but have instead opted to run with 2.9.9 for the moment (I'm a tad time-poor at the moment). That said, if I find a pocket of time to give it whirl myself, I'll follow this up with the outcomes.
In terms of what's happening under the hood, I believe the above links also do a decent job of explaining where things are falling over.
In any case, I sincerely hope that this is of some help to you.
